# Using Custom Code in Expressions (Reporting Services). Sum of calculated rows

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder I need to calculate total of several rows as sum of values in the tablix. I've read that for this purpose I can use the custom code, but I don't know how to integrate it into my report. An excerpt from the Internet:

> ```
> Dim public totalBalance as Integer
> Public Function AddTotal(ByVal balance AS Integer ) AS Integer
>                 totalBalance = totalBalance + balance
>                 return balance
>
> End Function
>
> Public Function GetTotal()
>                 return totalBalance
> End Function
> ```
>
> To use the code, please use the AddTotal in the ‘Balance’ field such
>   as: =AddTotal( change the Balance value based on the business role).
>   This expression will return the value of the balance that has been
>   changed based on the business role.
>
> And then in the footer, use this expression: = GetTotal().  That will
>   return the total value of the changed balance.

Can anybody explain step-by-step what should I do? 
I have values for SKU calculated in data textbox by custom expression. SKU is the child group of Brands. I need to calculate total for Brands (I added a Total row for Brands in which I need to get total).

Answer (score 1):

To add custom code, right click somewhere in the blank space around the report. Select "Report Properties", then "Code". Add the code from the grey box you pasted and click "Ok".  You have just created two new functions to use. Use =code.Addtotal(fields!yourfield.value or reportitems!yourfield.value) for the subtotal and =code.GetTotal(fields!yourfield.value or reportitems!yourfield.value) for the total row.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've done this. Can anybody tell is there any possibility to hide data rows (show only subtotals and total) using this method. Now when I hide rows, subtotals are equal 0.